# I get all contacts from my android phone in react-native but App crashed?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `react-native-contacts`. Using `getAll` code function from the documentation but App crashed sometime.

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  // contacts returned
  console.log(contacts)
})
```

**Error:** Unfortunately, App is stopped working.

Any other way the we can get contact. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try to fetch contacts in background

Comment: Thanks @RaviRupareliya i will be check.